# How to handle map when web page is zoomed in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, bing-maps

I have a webpage with iframe containing map. So my html looks like:

```
<div>
<iframe src="url" >
 <!Doctype html5>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe> 
</div>
```

Height of div with id "map" is 100% so div#map, iframe page body will have same width and height as the iframe has. Now, when user zoom in the page, i am resizing the iframe via javascript so that it looks exactly same as it was at zoom level 1.

When i resize iframe, its inner content div#map will also get resized (means its height and width will change according to iframe) but the map is still coming in zoomed in state.

Is there any way to show map as it was looking at zoom level 1? I am working with both bing and google map api.

Please help me out.

Comment: Do you have any working example? Like a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The map will not zoom when you resize the window. It might appear to be zoomed which is an optical illusion. Also, to ensure your map fills the full inside of the iframe make sure the map page has the following CSS styles:

```
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#map{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```